# Error while compiling react app - Error: Package exports for *path* do not define a valid '.' target

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I created a react application with "create-react-app" without any issues but I receive this error when the application tries to compile:

[image: Terminal snippet]

I'm running the command "npm start" to compile and prior to that I ran "npm install".

I'm suspicious of the path because I have a space in my username. Could that have any say in this?
or what could the issue be?

EDIT:
I changed the path so there is no space and created a new react app again. But the error persists.

Comment: I dont think space in path is the problem

Comment: Did you change anything after creating the app and before npm start?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. At the end the space in the path wasn't the problem.  I've posted my solution as answer to this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that my version of node (13.3) could have some issues regarding ES module support. **So updating node to the current latest version (13.7) fixed the problem.**

Credits to jorgebucaran's comment here:
https://github.com/jorgebucaran/colorette/issues/48